# log4j with tomcat does not log what is logged in mvn test

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, log4j

I have a web application. When I run 'mvn test', it logs the debug messages to console, as I have configured it. But when I deploy it to tomcat, I don't see the the logs of the application. I am absolutely sure that I got the log4j.properties file on the right place in the war, as when I change values in the deployed /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/worldmodel/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties for root logger or for hibernate and touch web.xml, I see/chease to see debug logs for hibernate. But I cannot get my application's debug messages to be logged with any configuration I've tried.
Here is how I do the logging:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

logger = Logger.getLogger(BaseObject.class);
log(Level.DEBUG,"message");
```

Here is log4j.properties for testing:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, CONSOLE

log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

log4j.appender.SYSLOG = org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.syslogHost = 127.0.0.1
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.Facility = LOCAL0

log4j.logger.org.rulez.magwas.worldmodel=DEBUG
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=debug 
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=trace
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=trace
```

here is the log4j.properties which gets deployed:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, SYSLOG

log4j.appender.SYSLOG = org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.syslogHost = 127.0.0.1
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.Facility = LOCAL0

log4j.logger.org.rulez.magwas.worldmodel=DEBUG
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=debug 
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=trace
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=trace
```

I get such lines in mvn test:

```
2013-05-21 07:12:17,751 [main] DEBUG org.rulez.magwas.worldmodel.BaseObject- setValue0e9é 072r 074t 0e9é 06bk
```

The whole project: https://github.com/magwas/worldmodel/commit/c6b08da0a733d9b61257c669e0cc4af9e59444be

edit:

ok, forget it, the code (getter and setter methods in a bean) seems not being been called, perhaps hibernate sets/gets the values directly?

Comment: Are you sure your Tomcat installation doesn't have another logger inside it?

Comment: Are you sure that the code that is doing the logging is getting called? Try replacing it with a sysout to confirm.

Comment: see the edit in the question. should I instantiate a logger for each class I am logging from?

Comment: Sorry. Yes, I see other logs in code which is surely called. Thank you for the help, and sorry to use your resources for such a n00b mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Since, you're configuring your ROOT logger with level INFO it won't display any DEBUG level messages.

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, SYSLOG
```

The above rootLogger should be configured as DEBUG to see debug and other higher levels (Fatal, Error, Warn and Info) in your logs.

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, SYSLOG
```

I'm not sure what your Maven test case configuration is but perhaps the `log4j.properties` you've shared isn't having any effect there.

**EDIT**: It seems from your edit that your logging in production is misconfigured. If your logging is set to INFO it should not log DEBUG messages. I mean, that simply defeats the purpose of having log levels, clearly shows Log4j has not been configured properly and drains Prod resources both space and time.